# '_resetstkoflw': identifier not found

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm upgrading a VC++ 6.0 project to VS2010 and I'm getting this error when compiling.

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlalloc.h(643): error C3861: '_resetstkoflw': identifier not found

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that  this compiler error was caused by my use of _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC and _INC_MALLOC macros that I was using.  _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC was for Microsoft memory leak detection and _INC_MALLOC excluded standard memory allocation procedures.  When I commented out those macros I was able to get past the _resetstkoflw compilation error.